# Wordpress themes under GPL license

Tags: themes, copyright

On a themes site they stipulate, in the terms and conditions, that their themes inherit the GNU general public license from WordPress. I believe that this means that they can be copied and modified.

However the themes are being sold. Shouldn't they be free? Could someone enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GPL absolutely *does **not** preclude selling* code, for cost. In fact, the terms of the license *explicitly allow* for selling of code.

The GPL merely allows the end user, whether he received the GPL-licensed code for free or for cost, to use the code however he likes, to redistribute the code, to modify the code, and to redistribute the modified code - provided that any such-distributed code be licensed under the same license.

Comment: If a user was to purchase a theme would he therefore be able to redistribute it freely, defeating the seller's intention?

Comment: Stack 101: Yes, however you would have to wonder about the motivations of such a person, to spend his own money on software and to then give it away for free.

Comment: @stack the PHP code is GPL'd - however, it's possible that the CSS and any images are not. Therefore, the theme might not be redistributable as a single package

Comment: So, I could take an HTML theme that was available for free as open-source GPLed software, modify it to my heart's content, convert it to WP, and promptly sell it somewhere, provided I included the same license?

Comment: @Amanda yes. If the work is licensed under GPL, you can redistribute that work - modified or unmodified - under the same license.